# Is it incorrect to use (type of variable) as condition? es-lint shows Unexpected constant condition

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm setting up a rest api in Javascript and need to check whether a parameter is a boolean.  I can do it using JSON.parse(variable)=='boolean', but this results in an eslint error (no-constant-condition).  I can disable the error for this line, but I'm curious if there is a reason not to do so.

I've read the documentation for the error.

> A constant expression (for example, a literal) as a test condition might be a typo or development trigger for a specific behavior. For example, the following code looks as if it is not ready for production.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition

As far as I can tell, it seems like ignoring it is ok.

```
try {
  if (!typeof JSON.parse(x) === 'boolean') {
    throw new Error('x must be boolean');
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw new Error('x must be boolean');
}
```

Comment: I think ignoring that is ok. But, I'd be much more concerned with your use of `try/throw/catch` as a validation technique. `try/catch` should only be used when the code may fail through no fault of the programmer (i.e. network errors, DB errors). For simple data validation, it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The `no-constant-condition` rule is working as expected. Your if statement will always evaluate to `false`. I'll break down the explination

1. `typeof JSON.parse(x)` will return a string of the type (`string`, `number`, `boolean`, etc.)
2. `!SOMETHING` will *always* return a boolean

   1. If `SOMETHING` is *falsy*, then `!SOMETHING` will be `true` (*not false*)
   2. If `SOMETHING` is *truthy*, then `!SOMETHING` will be `false` (*not true*)

That means you're comparing a `boolean`(type) to a `string` (type) with `===`. To fix your scenario you need to move the `!` (*not*) to the evaluator

```
try {
  if (typeof JSON.parse(x) !== 'boolean') {
    throw new Error('x must be boolean');
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw new Error('x must be boolean');
}
```